# Привет всем! начал изучать C# и столкнулся с такой проблемой в IDE, пожалуйста помогите

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Использую vsCode в качестве IDE и столкнулся с такой проблемой-при создании проекта vsCode по умолчанию выводит такой код, ниже на картинке.
[image: Код при создании проекта]

Данный код, как можно понять выводит `Hello, World!`.

Далее я стираю данный код и пишу свой код.

```
using System;

namespace project{
    class Program{
        static void Main(){
            Console.WriteLine("Привет");
        }
    }
}
```

Но vsCode всё равно выводит `Hello, World!`.

[image: RКартинка]

Comment: Если собираетесь пользоваться этим "блокнотом", то настройте правильно его, чтоб по F5 он запускал отладку, мог обрабатывать брейкпоинты (точки остановки) и так далее, тогда он и сохранять сам будет, и не надо постоянно в консоль писать всякое ненужное. А вообще, совет, особенно для новичка - поставьте нормальную студию, которая имеет все необходимое, а не этот кастрированный кусок непойми чего...

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в несохраненном коде, нажми:

```
Ctrl + S
```

Для его сохранения.

Также рекомендую плагин autosave, для автоматического сохранения кода, если в нем нет ошибок

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а как его настроить этот плагин?

Comment: просто установить, он работает автоматически

Comment: @vlad чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.